# How can I translate the webpage opened via Selenium to other language using JAVA?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
Map<String, Object> langs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
langs.put("en", selectedLanguage);
prefs.put("translate", "{'enabled' : true}");
prefs.put("translate_whitelists", langs);
Coptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
driver = new ChromeDriver(Coptions);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzyTd.png)

After Added the page content is not change. please give me any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

The above approach doesn't work anymore with Chrome. Below you can find a way that currently works. The language code can be taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/languages)

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "LANGUAGE_CODE");
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I tried also this one, but it is not working.

Comment: All the above code is working for some website like https://www.facebook.com/ or https://twitter.com/i/flow/login etc. which is accessible by globally. but when I try with https://www.goibibo.com/ that code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
 "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.addArguments("−−lang=bn");
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> langs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
langs.put("en", "bn");
prefs.put("translate", "{'enabled' : 'true'}");
prefs.put("translate_whitelists", langs);
prefs.put("intl.accept_languages", "bn");
opt.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);  
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//      driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
//      driver.get("https://www.icicibank.com/");
//      driver.get("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login");
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
}
}
```

Comment: @Alin Stelian for above code only it will work for above commented Link, but for https://www.goibibo.com/ not work. Can you please try this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).